# Remove Visual C++ Menu Bar

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

I'm fairly new at c++ programming, and yet I searched around and couldn't find an answer to how to do it, so I'm sorry if this is kind of a stupid question.

Anyway, I'm working on designing a custom window (in Microsoft Visual C++), and I just can't figure out how to remove the menu bar from the window.  This is what I'm referring to:

[image]

I used an image editing software to put a box around what i want to remove in the program in case i'm not referring to it correctly.  Anyway, please tell me what code to remove and/or edit to remove it.  (Also, a brief explanation of why would be good because i'm still new to this)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`SetMenu()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647995%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function to show or hide the menubar. Use it like this:

```
SetMenu(hwnd, NULL);
```

where `hwnd` is the handle to the window, which menubar you want to hide.

You can also try using the [`DestroyMenu()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647631%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function to destroy the menu, like this:

```
DestroyMenu(hMenu);
```

where `hMenu` is the handle to the menu you want to destroy.